# Help needed on using LINQ to SQL classes

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, orm

Already Generated the default classes. There are 2: 1. DataContext 2. Table object class

Now : 
1. how to add functionality (extend) to the data class. i created seperate partial class.

1. do i need to do any extension to data context ?
2. Do i need to call generated-class constructor inside my own custom constructor ?
3. How to create new instance of the data class ?

A concern is that the DB name (Databahn) and (i dont know what else) is tightly attached by dbml. If i change my DB name etc. in future how does this pan out ?

And can i change the class names. Don't want them to be same as DB table name ?

`[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="Databahn")]

    public partial class AgentsDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext`

Comment: What do you mean by 'add functionality (extend) to the data class'. What functionality are you thinking of?

Comment: I mean business logic to the object class (generated from table).

Comment: Also - if using VS2008SP1, watch out for the "my generated code evaporated when I added MyDataContext.cs" bug (fixed in VS2010). If you get hit by this there is a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally hand roll my own datacontexts and data objects as well for Linq to Sql. I'll create a sample datacontext, table object, and retriever method to show my little home made strategy here. We'll say my database name is "Main", my table object will be "dbo.Person" inside of sql.

here goes:

DataContext representing my databae:

```
internal class MainDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{
     private static MappingSource _mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();

     internal MainDataContext(string connectionString)
          : base(connectionString, _mappingSource) {}

     internal Table<PersonDto> PersonDtos { get { return GetTable<PersonDto>(); } }
}
```

Dto representing my table:

```
[Table(Name = "dbo.Person")]
internal class PersonDto
{
    private Guid _id;
    [Column(Storage = "_id", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public Guid Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    private string _name;
    [Column(Storage = "_name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    private DateTime _dateCreated;
    [Column(Storage = "_dateCreated")]
    public DateTime DateCreated
    {
        get { return _dateCreated; }
        set { _dateCreated = value; }
    }
}
```

Now finally PersonRetriever class:

```
public class PersonRepository
{
    private string _connectionString;

    public PersonRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    string GetPersonName(Guid personId)
    {
        using (var db = new MainDataContext(_connectionString))
        {
            string personName = string.Empty;

            PersonDto person = db.PersonDtos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == personId);

            if (person != null)
            {
                personName = person.Name;
            }

            return personName;
        }
    }
}
```

A few things to note: I declare a static mapping source in the datacontext to pass to the base data context, solely for keeping state when doing pre-compiled linq queries. It is not necessary, there is a base constructor that just takes in a connection string.

Also, make sure when declaring your Dtos, that the public property name matches EXACTLY to what your table in the database is. your private member can be named whatever you wish.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also explicitly implement an interface on your Dto object. (PersonDto : IPerson). That way when you retrieve from the db, you can just return the interface, and not have to make a mapping. This will help with layer separation.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type name in the dbml/designer. It doesn't have to be an exact match to the table name.

Re the constructor; to chain to another existing constructor you can use the `:this(...)` syntax after your constructors declaration (nut before the body).

No: you don't need to modify the data-context if you are just adding a partial class fragment.

Yo create a new instance just use `new` - it is the same type as it was before (a partial class just splits a type over several physical files that the compiler must merge).

Re the DB name in the data-context; it is common to pick up the connection details from config at runtime, in which case this is ignored.

Comment: i think i did not make my question clear :). I just got overwhelmed on seeing lot of auto-generated code for a simple table. Now i need to access the class, make objects, save into and query db simply. to that end, i wanted to know the general pattern to follow after generating linq 2 sql. how does anyone interact with those data classes. some example wud be very helpful.

Comment: @Munish - that is hard to do in a complete way in a short post; have you read the MSDN material? Or maybe "LINQ in Action"?

Comment: i guess so. hard to put it all here :) so will need to read thru all tht in detail seems. anyhow i dont have too many tables (abt 10), i just wanted to capitalize on existing tools to save labor on generating clases and DAL. may be the ROI wouldnt be in favour given the learning curve and unfamiliarity. i think these ORM tools are mainly for large DBs, unmanaegable on their own/

Comment: @Munish - that might be true for some ORM, but L2S is simple enough to provide great value even for a single table.